# ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground not working on white windowBackground

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to use

```
?android:attr/selectableItemBackground
```

for items of my recyclerview. Unfortunately it is not working. I have this line in my styles.xml file:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
```

Without this line I can see the ripple which means that the background os not working because of the whilte windowBackground. How can I force the ripppe effect to appear on my white background?

Here is the layout for recyclerview items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/brand_row"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/modelTitelColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_background"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>
</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/divider"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My minSdkVersion is 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my styles.xml  I was using

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

as parent theme. Changing it to

```
style name="CustomMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

solves the problem. Now I can see the effect.

Comment: This worked for me! I was trying to define a custom style extending Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog and all the selectableItemBackgrounds were no longer visible. Using Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog solved it all